# How to display AngularJS controller data in the HTML view?

Tags: html, angularjs

I want to display AngularJS controller data in the HTML template file. I have tried this:

My AngularJS controller code:

```
if(response.status  ==  'success') {
    $scope.lowcreditCtrl.data = response.data;
    console.log($scope.lowcreditCtrl.data);
}
```

The `response.data` object has all the output data I want to pass to my HTML view.

My HTML code:

```
<p>Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}</p>

<p> Hello {{$scope.lowcreditCtrl.data.firstName}}</p>
<p>{{$scope.lowcreditCtrl.data.lastName}}</p>
<p>{{$scope.lowcreditCtrl.data.email}}</p>
<p>{{$scope.lowcreditCtrl.data.credit}}</p>

<p>Your account credit balance {{lowcreditCtrl.credit}} is low. Please click the Add Credit button to update your account.</p>
```

This is the result of `console.log`-ing the data:

```
id: "7"
credit: "0.00"
firstName: "Rahul"
lastName: "Joshi"
email: "rahul@gdiz.com"
```

Comment: Try and do ‘$scope.$apply()’ after you assign your response to your $scope. Without some additional code, I am guessing you just need to run a digest cycle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the HTML view is bound to the JS controller, you don't need to prefix your variables with `$scope.`.

```
<p> Hello {{lowcreditCtrl.data.firstName}}</p>
<p>{{lowcreditCtrl.data.lastName}}</p>
<p>{{lowcreditCtrl.data.email}}</p>
<p>{{lowcreditCtrl.data.credit}}</p>
```